# How to link URL in flash media player to red5 server

Tags: streaming

I am trying to test a flash player for red5 live streaming video and in flash CS6 I have put a player component on the stage and not sure what url to input the live stream source?

I can test and see it working in mysite.com:5080/demos/publisher.html but cannot work out how to get that streaming video linked to my flash player.

update: it is not as simple as entering RTMP url as has failed on every attempt with all possible parameters and in any case the question now is what stops anyone from going to any given url with 5080 port and taking advantage...something to hash out in future with the help of mister AJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this particular product, but based on what you are describing, I think this may help.  The player in flash probably wants the actual streaming media link.  When you go to the html page, you are accessing an HTML page that probably has an embedded player.  Flash streaming actually uses RTMP rather than HTTP, so you would need to find out what the RTMP URL is and provide that to the Flash video player.

Update: So to do a live stream, you need to use the rtmp link to the publishing point on your server.  You then need to use the publisher to send a feed to that publishing point.  Whatever name you provide in the publisher will be the name of the file that you need to feed to your viewer.  Everything gets relayed through the server.

Comment: i have created the player and installed the red5 server but don't know what rtmp url to input..i must be missing many steps with javascript.

Comment: sorry , thanks for your answer but it is essentially my question.

Comment: @user5274 - if you can give the actual URL, I should be able to tell you what the RTMP link is from the source of that HTML page.  Alternately, if you view source on it, you should see an RTMP:// link, use that.  The http link doesn't work because the Flash player needs an RTMP stream, not an HTTP stream.

Comment: I know, I created the flash player in flash cs6 which adds vplayer component and you must add in that rtmp url- i cannot work out which rtmp link should be because the one on my server has my server IP not my home ip from where i am broadcasting- if you see what i mean?

Comment: @user5274 - The RTMP link will need to go to wherever your red5 server is running.  You should be able to enter it as a normal URI.  Have you been able to see the video running correctly anywhere?  If so, you can get the RTMP link from the source that allows you to view it.

Comment: @user5274 - I can jump in the Audio Video chat room if you want and we can discuss it at more length if you want.  It looks like you have enough rep on another SE site to be able to use the chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12227/discussion-between-aj-henderson-and-user5274)

Comment: it is all working in the demo and can see it stream live as well on mysite.com:5080/demos/ by putting in IP of my domain but I don't know how to get that link working on my site in a page because then somehow need to give IP of where CAM is streaming via player i created.